# Qt 5: read property inside Loader

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick, qtquick2

How to read property `timeout` located inside Loader object in Qt5 QML Quick 2.0?

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "black"

    property Component comp1 : Component {
        Rectangle {
            id: abc
            property int timeout: 5000
            width: 10; height: 10;
            color: "red"
        }
    }

    Loader {
        id: loader
        sourceComponent: comp1
    }

    Component.onCompleted: console.log( "timeout: " + loader.item.abc.timeout )
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeout' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code, namely:

1) You do not assign an `id` identifier to your component object.

2) You are trying to inherit `Component` with a property which is needless in this simple code.

3) You do not use the `item` property properly for the `Loader` element.

4) You are referring to a property name rather the `id` of the Component. This is again back to the needless inheritance.

Based on the [official documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qml-qtquick-loader.html), you should be doing something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "black"

    Component {
        id: comp1
        Rectangle {
            id: abc
            property int timeout: 5000
            width: 10; height: 10;
            color: "red"
        }
    }

    Loader {
        id: loader
        sourceComponent: comp1
    }

    Component.onCompleted: console.log( "timeout: " + loader.item.timeout )
}
```

Comment: It is good practice to use the "loaded" signal in the Loader to ensure the item has been loaded, for example, if "Loader.asynchronous" were set "true". In the Loader declaration: "onLoaded: console.log("timeout:", item.timeout)".